# How to make Ion menu with swipeEnabled false but enable swipe on slides within menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a requirement with slides to be available with ion menu. So I added slides within menu content. Then I faced issue with swipe.

The menu is getting closed When swiping. To fix that, I added swipeEnable="false" to ion menu. Then I am able to swipe the slides within menu. This solution is working fine in IOS but not working in android, in which the entire swipe is disabled and even slides are not swipeable.

How to fix this issue in Android?

Below is my code where menu swipe is disabled thus closing of menu will not happen with swipe however I am trying to swipe the content within menu with slides.

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" swipeEnabled="false">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-slides>
      <io-slide>
        <h1>Page1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Page2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Page3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Comment: Though, I am not able to swipe android slides in web view, its working fine with apk. The new issue I am facing is with pager. Pagination does not render buttons.

Comment: So if you solved this issue close the question and open another one

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are testing it, but the above works fine with me while testing on `Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)` as `Nexus 6P` or `Galaxy S5`

Comment: Did pagination get generated?  Could you please post your package.json settings